# How can I find the original index of a value from a subset defined by some condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I have an array of values and I want to do some form of gradient descent/ascent from a random starting point. If I have a matrix of values such as:

```
board = np.array([[ 2.41791045, -1.70149254, -1.85074627, -1.46268657,],
                  [-1.70149254, -1.91044776, -1.94029851, -1.85074627],
                  [-1.85074627, -1.94029851, -1.91044776, -1.70149254],
                  [-1.46268657, -1.85074627, -1.70149254,  2.41791045]])
```

I want to sample the 4 direct neighbours of my random starting index and return the index of the largest one. I can sample the neighbours easily enough by looping twice with the start indices -1, +1.

How do I go about finding the indices of the original array and not the values I have sampled to find the max? Doing a search for the calculated max value in the original won't always work because as you can see in my example the array is symmetric.

I should say I don't really want to manually create if statements for each direction because I want to keep it as general as possible, later I may want to be able to sample other sites or move to 3 dimensions.

Edit:
Sorry if I wasn't very clear in the original post. The ultimate objective is to move through the board down the gradient of the values until an exit point is reached (in this case the top right and bottom left corners). So for example if I start in position (2, 3) the value in the given example would be -1.701459. Then I want to know which of the 4 surrounding values is highest, and more importantly what the index is. The 4 values I would be sampling then would be from above, below, left and right (with wrapping). So if I start in position (2, 3) the 4 sampled values would be board[1, 3], board[3, 3], board[2, 2] and board[2, 0].

Here is the code I would use if I wanted to save them to a separate array first:

```
size = 4
start = np.random.randint(1, size - 1, 2)

samples = []
for x in (-1, 1):
    samples = np.append(samples, board[(start[0] + x) % size, start[1]])
for y in (-1, 1):
    samples = np.append(samples, board[start[0], (start[1] + y) % size])

optimalMove = max(samples)
```

However I don't just want the value of the max value, I want to know its position in the array "board" but I don't know how to do this.

Final edit:
I have solved my problem!

For anyone curious as to how I did it:
Firstly I created a boolean mask with the same shape as my board, then I set every value I did not want to consider to be NaN. Here is an example:

```
[[ 2.41791045         nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan -1.91044776         nan -1.85074627]
 [-1.85074627         nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]]
```

Finally I determined the highest value using numpy's nanmax command and grabbed the index of that using np.where. This also allowed me to create an array of all equal valued neighbours and to randomly select from those. Here is the code:

```
mask = np.ones_like(valueMatrix, dtype=bool)
for x in (-1, 1):
    mask[start[1], (start[0] + x) % size] = False
for y in (-1, 1):
    mask[(start[1] + y) % size, start[0]] = False

mask = mask.flatten()  # Flatten because np.nanmax() requires 1D arrays
dummyVal = valueMatrix.copy().flatten()
dummyVal[mask] = np.NaN
print(np.reshape(dummyVal, (size, size)))
position = np.where(dummyVal == np.nanmax(dummyVal))[0]

if len(position) > 1:  # Make sure only one value is chosen (at random)
    position = int(np.random.choice(position))

# These calculations convert the position value into co-ordinates to be used 
# as indices for the next move.
start = np.array([int(position % size), (int((position / size)))])

#  this whole thing goes in a while loop that continues until some exit 
#  position is landed on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you start by sharing some code of what you have tried.
Also, your objective is not very clear to me. 
You want to sample 4 neighbors (i imagine total of five samples from i-2:i+2)?.
From this set, you want to retrieve the index of the largest sample?

If this is correct, i'd go about it this way.

```
import numpy as np

# assuming idx is the desired index
def sample(board,idx, win):
    # creating a dummy variable here. You don't need this for your code
    board = np.array([[2.41791045, -1.70149254, -1.85074627, -1.46268657, ],
        [-1.70149254, -1.91044776, -1.94029851, -1.85074627],
        [-1.85074627, -1.94029851, -1.91044776, -1.70149254],
        [-1.46268657, -1.85074627, -1.70149254, 2.41791045]])

    tmp = idx - win + np.argmax(board.flatten()[idx - win:idx + win])
    max_idx = np.floor_divide(tmp, board.shape[0]), tmp % board.shape[0]
    max_val = board[max_idx]
    return (max_val, max_idx)
#sample(idx=10,win=2)
#(2,3)
```

## updated after OP provided clarity:

```
def sample(board=None,x=1,y=1, wlen=1):
    # creating a dummy variable here. You don't need this for your code
    if board is None:
        board = np.array([[2.41791045, -1.70149254, -1.85074627, -1.46268657, ],
                          [-1.70149254, -1.91044776, -1.94029851, -1.85074627],
                          [-1.85074627, -1.94029851, -1.91044776, -1.70149254],
                          [-1.46268657, -1.85074627, -1.70149254, 2.41791045]])
    x1=x-wlen
    x2=x+wlen
    y1=y-wlen
    y2=y+wlen

    x1=max(x1,0)
    x2=min(x2,board.shape[0])
    y1=max(y1,0)
    y2=min(y2,board.shape[1])

    grid = board[x1:x2,y1:y2]
    xy = np.unravel_index(grid.argmin(),grid.shape)
    min_val = grid[xy]
    min_xy = (x - wlen + xy[0], y - wlen + xy[1])

    return min_val,min_xy

#sample(x=2,y=3,wlen=1)
#(-1.9402985100000001, (1, 2))
```

Comment: I have added some clarification in the original post, hopefully that explains my goal better.

Comment: The code answer offered returns the max indices in the original array and I believe answers your original question. Can you verify or indicate how it fails to meet your requirement?
I will modify to include the max value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am misusing or misunderstanding your code, but it doesnt seem to be outputting the correct values. For example, when I input a start index of 10 (corresponding to [2, 2]) I get an output index of (2, 2), by looking at the array the output should be either (3, 2) or (2, 3) as both are equally the highest value neighbours.

Comment: After reading into your solution a bit more I think I understand it now and why it doesn't work. You flatten the array and then use one index to describe the position, but this means that only the neighbours the the left and right of the starting value can be considered, it also creates and odd wrapping problem where if the start is near the edge it also considers the value on the next row, which it should not. I only want to consider values one "step" away from the start up/down or left/right, not diagonally (in both directions).

Comment: This update should be made explicit in your post. Traversing a matrix is not the same as traversing a grid. 
In addition, you have not specified specifically what you are trying to do. I appreciate the update, but you should still specify how you want to compute boundary conditions. For example, what do you compare when you start at position [0,0]?

Comment: You're right, I should have made it more obvious that [0, 0] and [3, 3] are the end states, I thought it was implied by them being the highest values and saying I want to ascend the gradient. My overall goal was to input an initial start position, (eg [2, 3]) and then find the optimal move, ie the highest value out of the 4 possible steps in each direction. The matrix I showed above is not a random set of numbers, it is a set of "values" measuring the expected reward of being in that state, where [0, 0] and [3, 3] are high reward states. I did not want to complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: I think in the future, you should provide a background to what you are trying to do. it seems like you are manually coding conv NN. The typical approach is to pad. The update I provided does not pad but instead shrinks the size of the grid in to accommodate boundaries. 

An easy modification to this is to assert the x,y coordinates either in the method or the one that calls it.

Comment: I'm actually trying to solve a simple 2D maze using similar methods to how a NN would. I'm evaluating the value function directly through solving Bellman's equation instead of estimating it via a NN. Its certainly not the best way, but its a precursor to eventually solving this and much larger problems with NNs.

Comment: Such information will be useful in original post I think. Please check the current update and accept if it is a valid general solution to the problem.